# ZK @listen annotation

Tags: java, model-view-controller, controller, annotations, zk

I have the following problem: I have a zk page which contains four groupbox, whose id are "id_gb1", "id_gb2", "id_gb3" and "id_gb4".
I created a Java controller (extending GenericForwardComposer) in which I have the following lines:

```
[...]
@Listen("onClick = #id_gb1; onClick = #id_gb2; onClick = #id_gb3; onClick = #id_gb4")
private void onClick() {
  //do some stuff
}
[...]
```

and I set the value of the attribute apply of the window element in the zk file with the class name.
The problem is that when I click on the label of the groupbox nothing appens: furthermore, if I write in the same Java controller

```
[...]
public void onClick$id_gb1() {
  //do some stuff
}
[...]
```

it works!

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks,
Daniele

Comment: Which version of ZK you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some big changes [moving from ZK5 to ZK6](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/January/Envisage_ZK_6%3a_An_Annotation_Based_Composer_For_MVC#SelectorComposer).

ZK5:
Use `GenericForwardComposer` and `onClick$myButton` syntax.

ZK6:
Use `SelectorComposer` and `@Listen` annotations.

On the topic, ZK6.5 introduces the MVVM layout which you might want to look into if you're learning ZK.

Comment: thanks, can you link me an article which describes the MVVM pattern and the advantages of using MVVM instead of MVC or MVP?

Comment: For sure: [www.google.com/search?q=zk+mvvm](https://www.google.com/search?q=zk+mvvm)

Comment: This is an answer to the question "how to use MVVM in ZK", my question was a bit different, I was looking for an article in which the MVVM pattern and his advantages was explained :)... now i found it ;)

Comment: I will prefer MVVM Over MVC because its abstract lots of COde from developer the main advantage of MVVM is Loose coupling with View

Answer (score 1):

I used the `sclass` property for the components, and then in the controller I used only one @Listen for all similar components, which in turn had same the method to call.

zul file :

```
<toolbarbutton sclass="inLineBtns" .../>
<toolbarbutton sclass="inLineBtns" .../>
<toolbarbutton sclass="inLineBtns" .../>
```

Controller file which extends the `SelectorComposer` class:

```
@Listen("onClick = .inLineBtns")
public void doSomthing(){
...
}
```

Notice the dot, that indicates that it is a class name, not the component's ID.

Comment: @DanieleMilani no my friend , "sclass" is a pre-defined attribute for ZK components , you can use this attribute as easy as other attributes for each component ... if you need more detail , i can send complete code of both zul file and controller .

Comment: `sclass` is short for 'style class' and is a simple proxy for HTML's `class` attribute used for CSS ('class' is a reserved word in Java so couldn't be used). What you're doing here applying a CSS class to all these elements and attaching a listener to them.

Comment: if a component is include in another zul file,  then the sclass is very useful on @Listen anotation